# Convert object from one trait to another with generics

Tags: rust

The code I'm working on implements multiple traits for a few structs. There's a factory method that generates an object of one of these structs and returns it to my code. The object is returned as one of these traits, but I want to use a method of a trait that has a generic in it.

This code illustrates my problem:

```rust
struct Data {
    some_data: String
}

struct Data2 {
    some_data: i32
}

trait PrintableData {
    fn print(&mut self);
}

trait ConsumableData {
    fn consume<Callback>(&self, callback: Callback)
        where
            Callback: FnMut(String);
}

impl Data {
    fn new(data: String) -> Self {
        Data {
            some_data: data
        }
    }
}

impl Data2 {
    fn new(data: i32) -> Self {
        Data2 {
            some_data: data
        }
    }
}

impl PrintableData for Data {
    fn print(&mut self) {
        println!("{}", self.some_data);
    }
}

impl PrintableData for Data2 {
    fn print(&mut self) {
        println!("{}", self.some_data);
    }
}

impl ConsumableData for Data {
    fn consume<Callback>(&self, mut callback: Callback) where Callback: FnMut(String) {
        callback(self.some_data.clone());
    }
}

impl ConsumableData for Data2 {
    fn consume<Callback>(&self, mut callback: Callback) where Callback: FnMut(String) {
        callback(self.some_data.to_string());
    }
}

fn factory(data_type: i32) -> Box<dyn PrintableData> {
    match data_type {
        1 => Box::new(Data::new(String::from("123"))),
        2 => Box::new(Data2::new(123)),
        _ => panic!("panic")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let callback = |s: String| {};

    for data_type in 1..3 {
        let d = factory(data_type);
        (d as Box<dyn ConsumableData>).consume(callback);
    }
}
```

In short, the factory function returns either `Data` or `Data2` as `PrintableData`, but I need to use the object as `ConsumableData`, which has a generic method implemented in it.

Running this code generates the following error:

```rust
error[E0038]: the trait `ConsumableData` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:72:15
   |
72 |         (d as Box<dyn ConsumableData>).consume(callback);
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `ConsumableData` cannot be made into an object
   |
note: for a trait to be "object safe" it needs to allow building a vtable to allow the call to be resolvable dynamically; for more information visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/items/traits.html#object-safety>
  --> src/main.rs:14:8
   |
13 | trait ConsumableData {
   |       -------------- this trait cannot be made into an object...
14 |     fn consume<Callback>(&self, callback: Callback)
   |        ^^^^^^^ ...because method `consume` has generic type parameters
   = help: consider moving `consume` to another trait
```

Comment: Do you control the traits and types in question, or are some of them coming from dependencies and/or from downstream users?

Comment: @Cerberus Well I do have access to these types and traits but I'd rather not change them too much because the tests aren't very reliable

Comment: This looks very much like a XY problem. You cannot do exactly that. But if we will be given more details, perhaps we will be able to help.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman The traits in the illustration are pretty much what I'm working on just with different names. If it is not possible to do exactly what I showed in `main` then I'm open to changing them

Comment: You cannot call a generic method on `dyn Trait`. This is what Rust is telling you, and it is correct. However, there may be solutions. I'm just going blind because I have no information other than "I want to do this". Well, you can't.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman please lmk what info to provide. I do have full access to these types and can change them if necessary.

Comment: Can you go with the overhead of `dyn Fn`? Can you live with not be able to call the method on `dyn Trait` but doing so on `&dyn Trait`?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman at the moment I'm open to solutions. I probably won't be fully aware of implications though, but I'll see in the future.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to make `ConsumableData` object safe, so you will be able to work with it.

We can take a lesson from `Iterator` here: it has some non-object-safe methods that take `self`, for example `map()`. Still, it is object safe and you can work with `dyn Iterator` pretty conveniently. The secret sauce is three-staged:

1. Have a core method that is object-safe (`Iterator::next()`).
2. Implement all other methods in terms of it (possibly allow to specialize them for optimization, too).
3. Have a blanket implementation that forwards the implementation [on references](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/core/iter/traits/iterator.rs.html#3769-3784) ([and `Box`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.61.0/src/alloc/boxed.rs.html#1792-1806)).

Now, for regular objects you can just call the non-object-safe methods directly. But when working with `dyn Iterator`, you don't call, say, `<dyn Iterator>::map()`, because it is not object safe - rather, you call `<&mut dyn Iterator>::map()`. This is perfectly fine, since `&mut dyn Iterator` is `Sized`. This method forwards the actual work to `<&mut dyn Iterator>::next()` (by its default implementation), and it in turn forwards it into the actual `<dyn Iterator>::next()` - which it can, since `next()` is object safe!

We can make `consume()` object safe by changing it from taking a generic to take `&mut dyn FnMut`:

```rust
trait ConsumableData {
    fn consume_dyn(&self, callback: &mut dyn FnMut(String));
    fn consume<Callback>(&self, mut callback: Callback)
    where
        Callback: FnMut(String),
        Self: Sized,
    {
        self.consume_dyn(&mut callback)
    }
}
```

And the blanket implementations:

```rust
impl<T: ?Sized + ConsumableData> ConsumableData for &'_ T {
    fn consume_dyn(&self, callback: &mut dyn FnMut(String)) {
        T::consume_dyn(&**self, callback)
    }
}
impl<T: ?Sized + ConsumableData> ConsumableData for &'_ mut T {
    fn consume_dyn(&self, callback: &mut dyn FnMut(String)) {
        T::consume_dyn(&**self, callback)
    }
}
impl<T: ?Sized + ConsumableData> ConsumableData for Box<T> {
    fn consume_dyn(&self, callback: &mut dyn FnMut(String)) {
        T::consume_dyn(&**self, callback)
    }
}
```

Now implementors should implement (only or not, depends on the require performance characteristics) `consume_dyn()`, but they get `consume()` for free.

The last component is how to convert from `Box<dyn PrintableData>` to `Box<dyn ConsumableData>`. This can be done by providing a method in the `PrintableData` trait for that:

```rust
trait PrintableData {
    // ...
    fn into_consumable_data(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn ConsumableData>;
}

impl PrintableData for Data {
    // ...
    fn into_consumable_data(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn ConsumableData> {
        self
    }
}

impl PrintableData for Data2 {
    // ...
    fn into_consumable_data(self: Box<Self>) -> Box<dyn ConsumableData> {
        self
    }
}
```

Then finally:

```rust
let d = factory(data_type);
d.into_consumable_data().consume(callback);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=db64bf089030a3f55ec36fb648b37c59).